# How to loop over a list of dicts and print values of a specific key?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, dictionary

I'm new to Python and have (what I know to be a very simple) question.

Running Python 3.4.

I have a list that I need to iterate over and pull specific information out.  Here is a sample (truncated, many thousands of items) of the list (called parts):

```
[{'state': 'DEAD',
  'id': 'phwl',
  'type_name': 'GAME',
  'unit_structure': 'lattice',
  'vendor': 'Downward',
  'type_id': 'shiftable'
  'weight': 'heavy'},
 {'state': 'ALIVE',
  'id': 'a06c5',
  'type_name': 'BOARD',
  'unit_structure': 'frame',
  'vendor': 'Sniggles',
  'weight': 'light'}]
```

I want to do this using a for loop where I pull just the value after the `'id'` key and print it to my console. A simple for loop looks like this:

```
for i in parts:
    print(i)
```

This, of course, prints all the information in the parts list again, which isn't what I want.

So I need to do something like:

```
for i in parts:
    i = 'id'
    print(i)
```

This isn't correct because it just prints:

```
id
id
id
id
....etc
```

So I need to do something where I tell it "every time you see `'id'`, print the value after it, but I'm unsure how to structure that loop.

Can anyone give me some guidance?

Comment: Just use print(i['id']), it will give you the value related to that id.

Comment: Yep, this was correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly. You are looking for fetching a value using key from a dict.

**Ex:**

```
for i in parts:
    print(i["id"])   #or print(i.get("id"))
```

**Output:**

```
phwl
a06c5
```

**[MoreInfo in Python Dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)**

Comment: Yes, this was correct. What if I wanted to print both "id" and "type_name"?

Comment: Got it:
for i in parts:
print((i["serial_id"]), (i[type_name]))